# What does the Zune heart button mean?

Tags: zune-player

What does heart icon next to album image means? I couldn't find documentation for it anywhere. I guess it's favorite button, but I cannot find play favorite songs either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a rating system for songs. A hearted song means you like it and a broken hearted song means you don't like it. The software will play your hearted songs more often and your unrated songs less and your songs marked with a broken heart even less than that.

Answer (score 0):

The heart is a like/dislike option for a song. If selected, it means you like the song. This like feature is very useful in zune software. It gives you the ability to create an **Auto-playlist** for liked songs.

**NOTE:-** you can't do this on phone; as creating, editing and deleting playlist is restricted to zune software only

Answer (score 0):

The heart also allows Zune to automatically remove "Broken Heart" songs from your device automatically. In your sync setting on your Zune client, you'll see a checkbox for "Don't sync songs with (broken heart)".

I find it a great way to automatically get songs off my phone that I no longer like.